# Button changing after image moves over it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a "slide to confirm" button, the set up is a custom UIButton + a regular UIImageView, the image is passed to the button and the button listen to touches and move the image accordingly.
Everything is working great except for one detail after the button is released everything should go back to their initial state, yet the button stay changed as if its alpha was halved

[image: before]
[image: after]

i commented the alpha because the button was going to hide but i disabled that once i run into this problem, the problem happens regardless of setting the alpha or not.

This is the code for the custom button

```
class SlideButton: UIButton {

    var arrowImage: UIImageView?
    var initialLocation: CGPoint?
    var initialArrowPosition: CGPoint?

    func setArrow(arrow:UIImageView){
        arrowImage = arrow
        initialArrowPosition = arrow.frame.origin
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let touch = touches.first!
        let location = touch.location(in: self.superview)
        initialLocation = location
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            //self.alpha = 0.0
          }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.arrowImage!.frame.origin = self.initialArrowPosition!
            //self.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let currentLocation = touch.location(in: self.superview)
        arrowImage!.frame.origin.x = initialArrowPosition!.x - initialLocation!.x + (currentLocation.x)
    }
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that by implementing `touches` manually for a UIButton you are interfering with the button's own touch response. You are forgetting to call `super` for all of them, which you really need to do. But even better would be not to do that at all.

Comment: thanks @matt that fixed it! the default behavior of the button on touch is changing it a bit and by forgetting to do the super calls i broke it i wish you would have posted this as an answer since it is the correct answer! i am curious tho how would you make a slide to confirm button if not this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are remembering to call `super` for one of your `touches` methods:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
```

But for the other `touches` methods you've forgotten to do that, so you've broken the core functionality of the button.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to also add an override to touchesCancelled because you might not always hit the touchesEnded endpoint.

Comment: thanks! i will add that! but this will not solve the problem sadly